# Show Images from Database ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am new to ASP.net and have some problem to show images. My designer code is as bellow.

```
<div id="directory-logo-wrapper" class="floatright">
    <table id="wrapper1" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="../images/companylogo.png" alt="LogoWrapper" />
                <%--<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Visible="true" alt="LogoWrapper" />--%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

My code behind code is as bellow.

```
protected void ShowImageFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bytes = {};
    bytes = (byte[])GetData("SELECT UploadedLogo FROM Projects WHERE ProjectId =" +  id).Rows[0]["UploadedLogo"];
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    //Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
}

private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConnectionInfo.GetConnectionString();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Problem: how to set table:wrapper1 img src in code behind because it does not shown in code behind. I tried to do with Image1 but its also not accessing in code behind.

Please help me.

Thanks, Raja

Comment: You can use Asp:Image with ImageUrl know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this

```
<div id="directory-logo-wrapper" class="floatright">
    <table id="wrapper1" runat="server">
        <tr>
            <td>
               <img id="myimage" runat="server" src="../images/companylogo.png" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

You can access Src from Code Behind

Try like this

```
                    'Get byte array from image file in the database with basic query
                    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select [logo] FROM [dbo].[tblCompanyInfo]", GlobalUser.currentConnectionString);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    myAdapter1.Fill(dt);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        // Get the byte array from image file
                        byte[] imgBytes = (byte[])row["logo"];

                        // If you want convert to a bitmap file
                        TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
                        Bitmap MyBitmap = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(imgBytes );


                        string imgString = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes);
                        // Set the source with data:image/bmp
                        myimage.Src = String.Format("data:image/Bmp;base64,{0}\"", imgString);

                    }
```

**EDIT**

**Access Image inside GridView**

```
private string m_ConcatUrl;

protected void gridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image imgCtrl = (Image) args.Row.FindControl("imgCtrl");
        imgCtrl.ImageUrl = m_ConcatUrl;
    }
}
```

**(or)**

private string m_ConcatUrl;

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HtmlImage img = (HtmlImage) args.Row.FindControl("imgCtrl");
        imgCtrl.Src= m_ConcatUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP clearly said that the image is stored **in the database** - not in his filesystem....

Comment: @marc_s Sorry about it. Now i changed that

Comment: myimage is not accessible.

Comment: Set like this. <img id="myimage" runat="server" src="../images/companylogo.png" />. I have accessed myimage

Comment: First i define gridview. <asp:GridView ID="gvProject" CssClass="Gridview viewproject-th-col-remov" runat="server" then I used </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>. In this I used Image which is not accessible while other controls like LinkButtons are accessible. If I take it out of Gridview, the Image control accessible.

Comment: then my suggestion is you have to use Aso:image and access like in my solution that i have updated now

Comment: Hi Vignesh, still not worked. I used your suggested code but error coming on imgCtrl. imgCtrl does not exist. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try following way:

HTML:

```
     <div id="directory-logo-wrapper" class="floatright">
        <table id="wrapper1" runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src='<%# ImageUrl(ProjectId) %>' alt="LogoWrapper" />
                    <%--<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Visible="true" alt="LogoWrapper" />--%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
private string ImageUrl(int ProjectId)
    {
    byte[] bytes = {};
        bytes = (byte[])GetData("SELECT UploadedLogo FROM Projects WHERE ProjectId =" +  ProjectId).Rows[0]["UploadedLogo"];
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    return "data:image/png;image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
        //Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
    }

private DataTable GetData(string query)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string constr = ConnectionInfo.GetConnectionString();

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
        }
    }
    return dt;
}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Its giving me error on page load. Error is: CS1026: ) expected